# Disable input after submit and count array element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function limitofTags(){

    var tags = $('div').find('.tag').map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    var elem = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; ++i){
        //store array elements
        elem.push(tags[i]);

        if(elem.length < 2){
            $("#tags").prop('disabled',false);

        }
        else{
            $("#tags").prop('disabled',true);

        }
    }
}
```

As for html, it is small div with button. When I type tags in input textfield, it will be appended to div area. When tags are more than 2, input textfield will be disabled to prevent more tags from being added. After submit the form, div showed the same number of tags but input textfield won't stay disabled. So how to make input textfield stay disabled if tags are more than 2 in div?

Appreciate the insight or help. I have been searching for online answers but seem not to find what I need the input text disable after submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably check the length after the array is populated, and you're creating an `elem` array that is exactly the same as the `tags` array you have :

```
function limitofTags(){
    var tags = $('div').find('.tag').map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    $("#tags").prop('disabled', tags.length >= 2);
}
```

Comment: oh i see. it is easier. but still when i added tags on create page and it showed input disabled, after submit, on edit page, input doesn't stay disabled. so if i add one more tag, it will be disabled and it will be 3 tags, not 2 tags as supposed. why?

Comment: After a submit, the page reloads, and everything set or done with javascript is lost as there is no concept of state, it all starts over again on a new page load.

Comment: I see so is there a way to keep disabled state after submit?

Comment: Cookies, localstorage, or if you're submitting a form, add something that you can use on the serverside to set the disabled state on the next page.

Comment: i am not familiar with cookies. serverside - grails and i am still learning. ok i will look into it and see if i can get it working. if not i will ask for help again. thanks and appreciate the help!

Comment: In the function that sets the disabled (the above code) fill in a hidden input that is submitted, and use that on the serverside as any other form value and check if it's filled in or not, and just set the disabled property on the serverside based on that.

Comment: thanks again and i am looking into the files. thanks again :)

Comment: Hi again i realize that i didn't call the limitTags() into document.ready() so that why input didn't remain disabled. it worked now. thanks again for your help :)